# How to Upload CSV file in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

i want to uplod csv file in to java from flex screen ? How can i do that ? is it possible,if it is please tell me any one ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileReference class:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(serverUrl);
req.data = csvString;
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
loader.load(req);
```